# How can I reference a script on Globals?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Okay, so I found an interesting 2D input-based joystick in unity. How it works is pretty simple - you reference it as type(not GameObject but VariableJoystick, DynamicJoystick) and get it's Horizontal or Vertical value. My problem is that I simply can't make it work with the controller that I am given. It's based on the old input system. I don't know how much of dumb this question is but please help. I simply can't reference it by just dragging because it's an Globals script and it's not in any of the object, and I can't add it there either. I'd really like the help.

Controller: https://github.com/cjddmut/Unity-2D-Platformer-Controller
Joystick: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/joystick-pack-107631

A quick example of how joystick works:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class JoystickPlayerExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public VariableJoystick variableJoystick;
    public Rigidbody rb;

    public void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 direction = Vector3.forward * variableJoystick.Vertical + Vector3.right * variableJoystick.Horizontal;
        rb.AddForce(direction * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }
}
```

Globals.cs:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

namespace PC2D
{
    public class Input
    {
        public const string HORIZONTAL = "Horizontal";
        public const string VERTICAL = "Vertical";
        public const string JUMP = "Jump";
        public const string DASH = "Fire1";
    }
    public class Globals
    {
        // Input threshold in order to take effect. Arbitarily set.
        public const float INPUT_THRESHOLD = 0.2f;
        public const float FAST_FALL_THRESHOLD = 0.5f;

        public const int ENV_MASK = 0x100;

        public const string PACKAGE_NAME = "PC2D";

        public const float MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHECK = 0.01f;

        public static int GetFrameCount(float time)
        {
            float frames = time / Time.fixedDeltaTime;
            int roundedFrames = Mathf.RoundToInt(frames);

            if (Mathf.Approximately(frames, roundedFrames))
            {
                return roundedFrames;
            }

            return Mathf.CeilToInt(frames);

        }
    }
}
```

I couldn't include the player controller motor because it's too big to fit in here and it doesn't seem to have the needed scripts

I don't need ANY other controls besides the UI. I'd be very grateful for help because I couldn't find any better controller. The previous one was on 0.2.6 of new input system and it simply wouldn't work with the UI or touch controls. Updating it to 1.0.0 only broke the script(wasted 11 hours trying to fix them, gave up realising it's not meant to work with 1.0.0 at all and rewriting the scripts is not mine liking). At least try to describe the problem and the easiest solution please ^^

EDIT: honestly i'm not even sure it's Globals.cs I just couldn't find any other place where input is handled. that's why I left the controller on github haha. sorry i'm just too dumb

Comment: What exactly are you trying to reference? All members of `PC2D` are either `const` or `static`, so you refer to them in code just like any other `static` or `const` member of a class

Comment: Uhhh???? wha-- sorry i'm a bit new in scripting so I may not know such things... can you explain please?

Comment: what i need is to change it from reading unity button input to my own joystick which is float. i can't exactly reference the joystick atm

Comment: uhh how do i use it? sorry if it's a dumb question i'm just dumb

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think the answer is as easy as plug and play. I would recommend writing a new script that can take the inputs from the joystick object you have and map them to the [actions](https://github.com/cjddmut/Unity-2D-Platformer-Controller#platformermotor2d-methods) you want the platformer controller to perform. You can also check out their [PlayerController2D](https://github.com/cjddmut/Unity-2D-Platformer-Controller#playercontroller2d). Good luck!

Comment: I think I can check this out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Zorgarath, I found an extremely simple solution - Globals.cs wasn't the controls handler but PlayerController2D.cs was. Changing GetAxis etc to joystick.Horizontal and joystick.Vertical and making the jump and dash buttons separately connecting them to the script (holding the jump button check) made it completely supported by the scripts. I think you can also leave the old controls and use them too.